# Unable to resize the window in virtual box

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, guest-additions

I have the following issue when I try to install the OVA file the window pops up, however, I am unable to resize the window to actually process with the next part in virtual box. I tried to change display preferences but it's still showing me the same, the display is set to automatic.Please click the below link for the image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhpX3.png)

Comment: I suggest turning off display scaling (ie. setting it to 100%). You must log out and log back in for the change to fully take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, release it and press <kbd>Space</kbd>. Window's menu will pop up. Select *Move* and move your mouse. The window should now follow the pointer. Make sure the title bar is on screen and click to detach the moving window. Then grab the top border and drag it down to shrink the window vertically. Move it up by dragging the title bar until the whole window is on the screen. Rinse and repeat if necessary.

Comment: I don’t think this will work here. The window is simply too big for the screen. But maybe it’s resizable. /edit: Nope, while resizable, this is the minimum size: 895×759 pixels.